# removing labels on map image with open-cv

Tags: python, opencv, label

I used **open cv** to remove the labels from the map.
But after that, the place of the labels is still clear.
Have a better solution for removing labels?

[image: map image]
[image: removing labels]

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread("map.jpeg", 0)
image_filtered = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (101, 101), 0)
gradient_x = cv.Sobel(image_filtered, cv.CV_16S, 1, 0, 3)
gradient_y = cv.Sobel(image_filtered, cv.CV_16S, 0, 1, 3)
abs_gradient_x = cv.convertScaleAbs(gradient_x)
abs_gradient_y = cv.convertScaleAbs(gradient_y)
sobel_imgg = cv.addWeighted(abs_gradient_x, 0.5, abs_gradient_y, 0.5, 0)
thresholded = cv.threshold(sobel_imgg, 90, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
img_mask = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = thresholded)
kernel = np.ones((11, 11), np.uint8)
dilate_img = cv.dilate(img_mask, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8)
erode_img = cv.erode(dilate_img, kernel)
img_mask = cv.bitwise_or(erode_img, img)
plt.subplot(121);plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray");plt.title("with label"),plt.xticks([]);plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122);plt.imshow(erode_img, cmap="gray");plt.title("no label"),plt.xticks([]);plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think image processing approach is suitable here. If you want to obtain the roads under labels, you should better use the Google API or any other map (e.g. [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)).

Comment: Have you found any solutions yet?